# VS Code automatically enable venv on open

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, vscode-extensions, git-bash

I recently got a new Windows laptop and I installed VS Code with the Python extension, Python, and virtualenv. I installed a virtual enviornment in a parent folder of a directory and VS Code recognized it and set the enviornment to default for the child directory. However when I shut down VS Code and reopen it doesn't activate the virtual environment. The correct name displays in the lower right hand marker in the window. I have to execute the `source my-env/scripts/activate` command for it to work and the text `(my-env)` displays over the active terminal line.

How do I get VS Code to open my virtual enviornment.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments Please review your relevant settings, such as "python.terminal.activateEnvironment".

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work. If I manually call "source myenv/scripts/activate" it activates it. If I run "echo $VIRTUAL_ENV" it prints the correct location of my virtual enviornment, but it is not active.